# How do I perform an action on a website via a Java program?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to interact with websites via Java. It should be a desktop application which connects to the website and performs a defined action. How would I go about writing a program like that? Are there tools I can use? I'm at the very beginning of this project.

Comment: This is way too broad a question and rather vague. Maybe google a bit first...

Comment: I haven't tried anything, looking for a general direction to go, I want to be able to write a desktop application that can connect to a website and perform an action on a website, just wondering how it can be done, any suggestions?

Comment: seems you want to automate some user actions on a web page, you can use APIs like selenium (webdriver) etc which uses java, to achieve this.

Comment: here you can find some java code examples using webdriver: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: I've rephrased your question, thereby making it more clear that you're looking for tips on how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into a headless web-browsers, there are a number of them that allow you to programmatically interact with a webpage.

For a headless webkit that supports javascript you can try PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) although there are many others out there.